# How do i use the code to show the table on my site?

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm developing a soccer blog. I came across this site with a code for showing a league table on my site. How do i use the code to show the table on my site

Source https://www.fctables.com/widgets/

Code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="520" height="700" src="https://www.fctables.com/england/premier-league/iframe/?type=table&lang_id=2&country=67&template=10&team=&timezone=Pacific/Midway&time=24&po=1&ma=1&wi=1&dr=1&los=1&gf=1&ga=1&gd=1&pts=1&ng=1&form=1&width=520&height=700&font=Verdana&fs=12&lh=22&bg=FFFFFF&fc=333333&logo=1&tlink=1&ths=1&thb=1&thba=FFFFFF&thc=000000&bc=dddddd&hob=f5f5f5&hobc=ebe7e7&lc=333333&sh=1&hfb=1&hbc=3bafda&hfc=FFFFFF"></iframe>
<div style="text-align:center;"></div>
<a href="https://www.fctables.com/england/premier-league/" rel="nofollow">FcTables.com</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the Iframe Code from the table you want to use and add it into your HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
   <iframe frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" width="520" height="700" src="https://www.fctables.com/uefasupercup/iframe=/?type=top-scorers&lang_id=2&country=67&template=36&team=180231&timezone=Pacific/Midway&time=24&limit=10&ppo=1&pte=1&pgo=1&pma=1&pas=1&ppe=1&width=520&height=700&font=Verdana&fs=12&lh=22&bg=FFFFFF&fc=333333&logo=1&tlink=1&ths=1&thb=1&thba=FFFFFF&thc=000000&bc=dddddd&hob=f5f5f5&hobc=ebe7e7&lc=333333&sh=1&hfb=1&hbc=3bafda&hfc=FFFFFF"></iframe><div style="text-align:center;"></div><a href="https://www.fctables.com/uefasupercup/" rel="nofollow">FcTables.com</a>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Style it in your css as you want it after.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section like this.
**4. Paste this code on your website**

There is a generated iframe tag. You can copy that iframe tag and paste it in your blog wherever you want. The table will be shown within your site.

```
<iframe frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" width="520" height="700" src="https://www.fctables.com/england/premier-league/iframe=/?type=top-scorers&lang_id=2&country=67&template=10&team=185904&timezone=Pacific/Midway&time=24&limit=10&ppo=1&pte=1&pgo=1&pma=1&pas=1&ppe=1&width=520&height=700&font=Verdana&fs=12&lh=22&bg=FFFFFF&fc=333333&logo=1&tlink=1&ths=1&thb=1&thba=FFFFFF&thc=000000&bc=dddddd&hob=f5f5f5&hobc=ebe7e7&lc=333333&sh=1&hfb=1&hbc=3bafda&hfc=FFFFFF"></iframe>
```